# journalctl --disk-usage shows 106M while journalctl | wc -c shows only 7MB of logs, why?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, journalctl

I have an issue with journalctl, I set it to use 100M maximum in my journald.conf:

```
[Journal]
Compress=yes
SyncIntervalSec=5m
SystemMaxUse=100M
ForwardToSyslog=no
ForwardToKMsg=no
ForwardToConsole=no
ForwardToWall=yes
LineMax=48K
ReadKMsg=yes
```

Which for some reason gives me only 2 days of logs. When I run journalctl --disk-usage it shows:

```
$ sudo journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 106.0M in the file system.
```

However, when I run journalctl | wc -c, it shows there is only 7MB of logs:

```
$ sudo journalctl | wc -c
7429593
```

Why is journalctl only giving 7MB of logs (2 days) while using 106MB? Where is the extra space going?

Comment: can you check journal log location I hope you are doing archiving.

Comment: I am, the archives are in /var/log/journal/4978883f003443d9a028798e7f5a40a4 and that takes up 107MB, but sudo journalctl -a doesn't seem to be accessing those archives.

Answer (score 0):

If you check output ***Archived* and active journals take up 106.0M in the file system.** mean it include archived logs too.
Check below location you come to know exact size of total journal logs

```
# ls -lthr /run/log/journal/<id>/
total 544M
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 32M Jun 25 19:13 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jun 27 04:00 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jun 28 14:38 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jun 30 01:16 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  1 11:56 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  2 22:36 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  4 09:10 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  5 19:48 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  7 06:20 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul  8 17:00 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul 10 03:42 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul 11 14:20 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 40M Jul 13 00:59 system@<some id>.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 32M Jul 14 04:31 system.journal
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that if I do du -sm /var/log/journal/4978883f003443d9a028798e7f5a40a4, that shows 107MB. But my understanding was that sudo journalctl -a should show archived logs as well? -- if not, how do I access the archived logs?

Comment: use like this `journalctl --since "2019-07-01" --until "2019-07-010 03:00"` to get msg between specific time.

Comment: I don't, I only get the last 2 days which amounts to around 7MB of the 107MB of logs. That's the question :(

Answer (score 0):

Default --output=short does not show all of the fields. Including fairly large boot ID and timestamps with every entry.

--output=export is not exactly like the on disk format, as lots of text with name=value. However, as a serialization stream it is closer to the real size.

```
# journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 56.0M on disk.
# journalctl | wc -c
5420238
# journalctl -o export | wc -c
34683172
```

The remainder I am not entirely sure. [Journal file format spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/) mentions everything is padded to 64 bit alignment. Possibly metadata like array and tag objects also take up space.

Comment: I tried on another machine and there I am seeing journalctl -o export is giving 44MB uncompressed while --disk-usage still shows 106M compressed (same size when I do du -sm /var/log/journal/4978883f003443d9a028798e7f5a40a4), so there seems to be a huge unexplained discrepancy hmm.